# How to set whole page data to CookieService in angular2

Tags: angular, cookies

I am using angular2. I have a page where i have list of items, on click of one items its details will show in the 2nd screen.

So when i am in the 2nd screen ,if i am refreshing the page whole page data is going.So to avoid this i want to use CookieService.

Suppose i have a method like below

```
  loadItemDetails(){

       this.itemDetailsData = this.customerService.selectedcustomer;
       return this.itemDetailsData ;
}
```

So in this **this.itemDetailsData** i have all the details of perticular item.

How to use CookieService here to save this data,and how to get it after the page refresh.

```
   public setDetails(){

        this.cookieService.set('','');

    }
```

this cookieService.set is asking for a key value pair.But in my case itemDetailsData is an array.

Can anyone please help me how to do this.

Comment: The key- value pair in this situation has nothing to do with your data type. The key here is a string - you choose it - in order to use it later to retrieve your data.

`this.cookieService.set('myData',data);`

Later you will use 'myData' to read your cookies

`this.cookieService.get('myData');`

Comment: Yeah @Jameel But when i am doing like this i am getting an compile time error 

[ts] Argument of type 'any[]' is not assignable to parameter of type 'string'.

Comment: Could you please tell more about the `CookieService` that you use? is it a npm module? or you defined it by yourself?

Comment: Have you thought about a workaround in case your user turned off the local storage and cookies?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of the CookieService, try local storage. It works basically the same way.

```
localStorage.setItem('whatever', 'something');

localStorage.get('whatever')
```

https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/API/Window/localStorage